# How to scroll from bottom to top in C#(Windows Phone 8 Dev) like in Chatting Applications?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, messagebox

I want to insert a area in my page so that it can be scrolled up to load more items.

For e.g Like in Messenger Apps when we chat last message is at the bottom of the panel.

So to add this type of panel which UI XAML control i need to use? Can somebody help me with this problem? A Sample Example will be very helpful.

Comment: well you can set ScrollViewer..ScrollToVerticalOffset(0). but if you want to go in slow motion scroll then you need to set up animation style or go few by few with a thread sleep...